# How to correct asyncio yield from in data_received

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, httpserver, python-asyncio

I would make async request to database in data_received function, but i don't know how do it. I wrote simple HTTPServer with asyncio.sleep(2), but it doesn't work.

```
import time
import asyncio

class HTTPServer:
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        pass

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        pass

    def eof_received(self):
        pass

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def data_received(self, data):
        try:
            #time.sleep(2)
            yield from asyncio.sleep(2)

            body = "Hello <br/>\n"
            response = 'HTTP/1.1 {status}\r\n'.format(status="200")
            response += 'Content-Length: {size}\r\n'.format(size=len(body))
            response += 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n'.format(size=len(body))
            response += 'Connection: close\r\n'.format(size=len(body))
            response += '\r\n'
            response += body
            self.transport.write(response.encode('utf-8'))
        except e:
            print (e)
        self.transport.close()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
print ('Start server on 0.0.0.0:8080')
asyncio.ensure_future(loop.create_server(
    lambda: HTTPServer(),
    '0.0.0.0', 8080
))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
    pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    loop.stop()
```

I comment line @asyncio.coroutine and yield from asyncio.sleep(2), it's works. I add time.sleep(2) instead asyncio.sleep(2), it's works. But async does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Protocol" you're using is from (quoting the documentation):

> 18.5.4. Transports and protocols (callback based API)

As explicitly told by the documentation, it's a "callback based API", which calls normal methods, and you can't change that, so wrapping `data_received` in "@asyncio.coroutine" just won't work.

But there's a coroutine based API, it's the next chapter in the documentation:

> 18.5.5. Streams (coroutine based API)

Rewriting your example using the coroutine based API, you get:

```
import asyncio


async def request_handler(reader, writer):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print("Received %r from %r" % (message, addr))

    body = "Hello <br/>\n"
    response = 'HTTP/1.1 {status}\r\n'.format(status="200")
    response += 'Content-Length: {size}\r\n'.format(size=len(body))
    response += 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n'.format(size=len(body))
    response += 'Connection: close\r\n'.format(size=len(body))
    response += '\r\n'
    response += body

    writer.write(response.encode('utf-8'))
    await writer.drain()
    writer.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(request_handler, '127.0.0.1', 8080, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

print('Start server on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

Note that if you're using Python 3.5 you can use `async def`  and `await` instead of `@asyncio.coroutine` and `yield from` as I did.